# Loop on Google Script ignore if statement

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have made function that will insert new row and copy to the first and second column some data from another sheet. If there is N/A error in P and Q column together I want my function to copy data from column A and B on the same row. It's actually work, add row and stuff but it copying all data even if there is not N/A error row by row

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MainShops");
var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ShopsData");



function AddShops() {



  for(j=2; j < 278; j++) { 

  var DoubleRowCheck = ssd.getRange(j, 16, 1, 2).getValues();

  if (DoubleRowCheck ==  "#N/A", "#N/A") {

  var ShopsToAdd = ssd.getRange(j, 1, 1, 2).getValues();
  var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var LastRowPlusOne = LastRow + 1;                            
  ss.insertRowAfter(LastRow);
  ss.getRange(LastRowPlusOne, 1, 1, 2).setValues(ShopsToAdd);

      }

  else {

    continue;

       }
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is with that statement:

```
 if (DoubleRowCheck ==  "#N/A", "#N/A")
```

This will always return "true". The `getValues()` method you use to init your value `DoubleRowCheck` returns a bi-dimensional array (rows, columns). You should check both columns values in first (and only) row individually in your "if" statement to verify if they equal "#N/A":

```
if (DoubleRowCheck[0][0] == "#N/A" && DoubleRowCheck[0][1] == "#N/A"){...}
```

Also, note that:

(1) the four last lines in your if statement could be replaced by the `append(ShopsToAdd)` method (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)))

(2) the else statement isn't necessary, your "for" loop will continue until it reaches the `j < 278` limit or a `break` statement.